# Unhandled Exception: setState() called after dispose()

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to receive notifications in my flutter app using Firebase Messaging to display them in the app, but I keep getting the error:

```
/FLTFireMsgReceiver( 6823): broadcast received for message
E/flutter ( 6823): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: setState() called after dispose(): _TipsState#aa4df(lifecycle state: defunct, not mounted)
E/flutter ( 6823): This error happens if you call setState() on a State object for a widget that no longer appears in the widget tree (e.g., whose parent widget no longer includes the widget in its build). This error can occur when code calls setState() from a timer or an animation callback.
E/flutter ( 6823): The preferred solution is to cancel the timer or stop listening to the animation in the dispose() callback. Another solution is to check the "mounted" property of this object before calling setState() to ensure the object is still in the tree.
E/flutter ( 6823): This error might indicate a memory leak if setState() is being called because another object is retaining a reference to this State object after it has been removed from the tree. To avoid memory leaks, consider breaking the reference to this object during dispose().
E/flutter ( 6823): #0      State.setState.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1085:9)
E/flutter ( 6823): #1      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1120:6)
E/flutter ( 6823): #2      _TipsState.getNotification.<anonymous closure> (package:stock_baba/Screens/Tips.dart:38:9)
E/flutter ( 6823): #3      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1434:47)
E/flutter ( 6823): #4      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1335:19)
E/flutter ( 6823): #5      _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1244:7)
E/flutter ( 6823): #6      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:341:11)
E/flutter ( 6823): #7      _DelayedData.perform (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:591:14)
E/flutter ( 6823): #8      _StreamImplEvents.handleNext (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:706:11)
E/flutter ( 6823): #9      _PendingEvents.schedule.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:663:7)
E/flutter ( 6823): #10     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1418:47)
E/flutter ( 6823): #11     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1328:19)
E/flutter ( 6823): #12     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1236:7)
E/flutter ( 6823): #13     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1276:23)
E/flutter ( 6823): #14     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1426:13)
E/flutter ( 6823): #15     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1328:19)
E/flutter ( 6823): #16     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1236:7)
E/flutter ( 6823): #17     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1276:23)
E/flutter ( 6823): #18     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:40:21)
E/flutter ( 6823): #19     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:49:5)
```

The PushNotification class is a simple class with the string fields title, body, dataTitle and dataBody.
My code is as follows:

```
class _TipsState extends State<Tips> {
  final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
  final List<PushNotification> messages = [];
  PushNotification? _notificationInfo;

  @override
  void initState() {
    getNotification();
    super.initState();
  }

  void getNotification() async {
    NotificationSettings settings =
        await _firebaseMessaging.requestPermission();

    if (settings.authorizationStatus == AuthorizationStatus.authorized) {
      print("Permission granted!");

      FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
        PushNotification notification = PushNotification(
            title: message.notification?.title,
            body: message.notification?.body,
            dataTitle: message.data['title'],
            dataBody: message.data['body']);

        setState(() {
          _notificationInfo = notification;
        });

        if (notification != null) {
          showSimpleNotification(Text(_notificationInfo!.title!),
              duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
              subtitle: Text(_notificationInfo!.body!));
        }
        print(notification);
        print(message.data);
      });
    } else {
      print("Permission declined!");
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: messages.isEmpty
          ? Container()
          : ListView(
              children: [Text(messages[0].title!)],
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried wrapping my setState() with mounted() but it didn't work.

How can I resolve this issue and display the incoming notifications in my app?

Comment: I think that you should listen for the messages outside of a widget and update widget tree when notification arrives .

Comment: I think you don't need setstate to show notification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is my code and its in working ..copy the code and make a dart class and paste it . your notification start working

use there plugins

> ```
>   firebase_core: ^1.11.0
>   firebase_messaging: ^11.2.5
>   flutter_local_notifications: ^9.2.0
> ```

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:vcare/firebase_options.dart';

class NotificationHelper {
  NotificationDetails get _ongoing {
    const androidChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'customer-channel-id',
      'customer-channel-name',
      importance: Importance.max,
      priority: Priority.high,
      ongoing: false,
      autoCancel: true,
    );
    const iOSChannelSpecifics = IOSNotificationDetails();
    return const NotificationDetails(android: androidChannelSpecifics, iOS: iOSChannelSpecifics);
  }

  // Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  // If you're going to use other Firebase services in the background, such as Firestore,
  // make sure you call `initializeApp` before using other Firebase services.
  // await initFirebase();
  // }

  configure() async {
    await initFirebase();
    FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
    await requestPermission(messaging);
    final String? token = await messaging.getToken();

    // FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

    final notification = await setupLocalNotification();
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      showNotification(
        notification,
        title: message.notification?.title,
        body: message.notification?.body,
        payload: message.data,
        type: _ongoing,
      );
    });

    return token;
  }

  Future<void> requestPermission(FirebaseMessaging messaging) async {
    await messaging.requestPermission(
      alert: true,
      announcement: false,
      badge: true,
      carPlay: false,
      criticalAlert: false,
      provisional: false,
      sound: true,
    );
  }

  Future<void> initFirebase() async {
    await Firebase.initializeApp(
      options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
    );
  }

  setupLocalNotification() async {
    const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid = AndroidInitializationSettings(
      'notification_icon',
    );
    final IOSInitializationSettings initializationSettingsIOS = IOSInitializationSettings(
      onDidReceiveLocalNotification: (int id, String? title, String? body, String? payload) {},
    );
    final InitializationSettings initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
      android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
      iOS: initializationSettingsIOS,
    );
    var notification = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    await notification.initialize(initializationSettings, onSelectNotification: (_) {});
    return notification;
  }

  showNotification(FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin notifications,
      {required String? title, required String? body, required NotificationDetails type, required payload}) {
    notifications.show(Random().nextInt(100), title, body, type, payload: json.encode(payload ?? {}));
  }
}
```

and then call this class in main.dart file here is the code

```
   WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      String? token = await NotificationHelper().configure();
    
     _storeFCMToken(token);

      print("deviceToken $token");
```

if you find any problem please let me know. if you find this code is helping you .then please mark my answer as accepted

Comment: What is the _storeFCMToken(token); supposed to do?

Comment: its a funtion to store token in local database

Comment: so I'll have to create the function, right?

Comment: no its not necessary. just romove it

Comment: I should call the widget in the screen in which i have to show the notification or the main.dart file?

Comment: in the main file ..and in the main method after this line    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

Comment: How do I display the data in the notification in my screen?

Comment: there are two types of notification local or you send notification from Firebase ..what you want..? local notification is like when you click on button ..screen show a notification..?

Comment: I'm sending notifications from Firebase and I have to show them in the screen

Comment: code work is done . have you setup the notification.. ? if not watch some tutorial

Comment: I am able to receive the notifications from FCM, but I also need to show the message on the screen. What do I use to do that?

Comment: are you receiving notification on your application.. ?

Comment: yes I am getting them on my emulator

Answer (score 2):

Cancel the `Stream` after dispose it

Create `StreamSubscription` variable

```
  StreamSubscription messagingSubscription;
```

Assign variable to your `listen`

```
....
messagingSubscription = FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
```

`Dispose` your `StreamSubscription`

```
  @override
  void dispose() {
    messagingSubscription?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Comment: That worked! How can I display it in my app?

Comment: you can listen `FirebaseMessaging` on your dashboard/home page